# Update column of tableA with idcolumn of tableB when is defined condition

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two tables A and B, I need to populate column of table A with ID of table B only when `TableA.name` is a part of `TableB.name`

I mean:

```
TableA
id   name   id.tableB
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    c
5    d

TableB
id.  name
1    abc
2    def
```

When `TableA.name` is part of `TableB.name` I need to populate `id.TableB` with corresponding ID. Eg. `TableA name = a` is a part of `TableB name = abc` so i put `id.TableB = 1` to `TableA` and next one and next one.

I try to make it with foreach condition like this:

```sql
foreach ($tableA as $A) {
    foreach ($tableB as $B) {
        if (strstr($B['name'], $A['name'])) {
            DB::update("update tableA set id_tableB = " . $B['id']);
            }
    }
}
```

But this foreach populated my all rows with 1 id and does is not correct

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: @jarlh becouse I know it can be done with swome SQL condition UPDATE tableA SET TableA.id.TableB WHERE... but I don't solved out how to write rest of this

Comment: Well of course an UPDATE statement without any WHERE clause whatsoever applies to _all_ rows … so _add one_, if you don’t want that?

Comment: I see. I thought you wanted a Laravel answer.